# Display all occurrences of duplicates using base R

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3), y = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3))
> df
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 1
3 1 2
4 2 3
5 3 3
6 3 3
> df[duplicated(df),]
  x y
3 1 2
6 3 3
```

As we can see above, the rows with `(x, y) = (1, 2)` and `(x, y) = (3, 3)` have been marked as a duplicates.

**Using only base R** (i.e., no additional packages are to be loaded), is there a way to get **all** rows in `df` that have an `(x, y)` pair identical to an `(x, y)` pair for a row in `df[duplicated(df),]`? In this case, the desired output is

```
  x y
1 1 2
3 1 2
5 3 3
6 3 3
```

I am particularly looking for a solution that would be ideal for explaining to someone who is new to R.

Comment: I think this is roughly what you want `df[duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast=TRUE),]`.

Comment: @lmo Well, I learned something today! Please feel free to post that as an answer, so that I can award you some points.